# Are there infinitely many pythagorean triples?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I believe these questions are all asking different things, but:

> - Are there infinitely many (integer) solutions to the pythagorean theorem?
> - Is every positive integer part of a solution to the pythagorean theorem?

Also, is there a difference in multiplying the pythagorean triple by a constant factor, let's say $k$, on both sides and multiplying each number $a, b, c$ by a constant $k$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: I am assuming your first question meant to ask about *integer* solutions, so I edited accordingly. Cheers

Answer (score 10):

As stated in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple), the set of ALL pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ is given by:
$$
a = k(m^2 - n^2) \;;\quad b = k(2mn) \;;\quad c = k(m^2 + n^2) \tag{1}
$$
where $m, n, k$ range over the positive integers, $m - n$ is odd, $m > n$, and $m,n$ are relatively prime. You can also switch $a$ and $b$ above, if you like, to get all triples where order of (a,b) matters.
So anyway, to answer your questions:

1. Yes, there are infinitely many pythagorean triples. The easy way to show  this is to take one triple, say $3, 4, 5$, and take all multiples of it.
   That corresponds to letting $k$ range over all integers in (1).
   But there infinitely many *primitive* triples, too (ones that aren't just multiples of a smaller triple); this is because there are infinitely many pairs $m, n$ with $m - n$ odd, $m > n$, and $m, n$ relatively prime.
2. For any integer multiple of four $l$, you can certainly write it as $l = 2mn$ with $m,n$ relatively prime, $m - n$ odd.
   For an odd integer $l \ge 3$, note that it is the difference between consecutive squares, so take $m = n+1$, where $l = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1$. For an even integer $l \ge 6$ that is not a multiple of four, it won't be part of a *primitive* triple, but it will be part of a triple--just find a triple for $\frac{l}{2}$, and then multiply each term by $2$.

**In summary:**

- There are infinitely many pythagorean triples.
- There are also infinitely many *primitive* pythagorean triples.
- Every positive integer $\ge 3$ is part of a pythagorean triple.
- Every positive integer $\ge 3$ that is not congruent to $2$ mod $4$ is part of a primitive pythagorean triple.
- $1$ and $2$ are not part of any pythagorean triples, though they would be part of $0, 1, 1$ and $0, 2, 2$ if we allowed these trivial cases.

---

P.S. You may also be interested in the [infinite tree of primitive pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples).

Comment: So some prime numbers aren't part of any integer solutions?

Comment: @Devon Every prime number is part of a pythagorean triple. (Every integer is.) All prime numbers except $2$ are part of primitive pythagorean triples.

Comment: Excellent. I've just been trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @Devon Keep in mind that $0$, $1$ and $2$ belong to pythagorean triples only if you count $(0,1,1)$ as a triple.  This is explicitly excluded from the Wikipedia definition (presumably because it corresponds to a degenerate triangle); if you do count it then it is trivial that every number is part of a (not necessarily primitive) triple.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks for the catch, I fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation of Euclid's formula generates positive, nontrivial triples for every pair of natural numbers $m,n$.

$$A=(2m-1+n)^2-n ^2\qquad B=2(2m-1+n)n\qquad C=(2m-1+n)+n^2$$

Another way of expressing this formula is
$$A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\qquad B=2(2n-1)k+2k^2\qquad C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2$$

Both generate the same triples to infinity in distinct sets.

Here is a sample of these sets where $GCD(A,B,C)$ is the $n^{th}$ odd square where $n$ is the set number.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & Triple_1 & Triple_2 & Triple_3 & Triple_4 & Triple_5   &  Triple_6  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61 & 13,84,85 \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89 & 45,108,117 \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 & 85,132,157 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 & 133,156,205 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 & 189,180,261 \\ \hline
Set_{6} &143,24,145 &165,52,173 &187,84,205 &209,120,241 &231,160,281 & 253,204,325 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score -1):

That should be the easiest one:

Let n be a factor of every Integer in a pythagorean triple:

n* 3sq + n* 4sq = n* 5sq

There are infinitely many positive integers and so also infinitely many n´s. Now we just need to show that the pythagorean triples are all correct with the factor n:

n* 3sq + n* 4sq = n* 5sq         (factoring out n)

n(3sq + 4sq) = n* 5sq            (:n)

3sq + 4sq = 5sq

This shows that the factor can be "ignored" and every pythagorean triple of that sort works and that there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this is a not very good answer to an old question that already has several good ones. This wastes your time and the time of those of us who track questions with new activity. If you want to contribute, answer new questions. Please use mathjax to format mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference